# Haskell: Exception with fromJust function

Tags: haskell

I wrote the following function in haskell

```
payment ::  [(Integer , Integer)] -> Integer ->  [(Integer , Integer)] -> Maybe  [(Integer , Integer)]
payment portemonnaie amount cashier | content (fromJust (pay portemonnaie amount)) - amount == 0 = Just []
                                    | pay portemonnaie amount == Nothing = Nothing
                                    | otherwise = payExact cashier (content (fromJust (pay portemonnaie amount)) - amount)
```

The problem here is: The function pay returns a Maybe type. So when the function 'pay' returns Nothing I get the following exception:

```
*** Exception: Maybe.fromJust: Nothing
```

I tried to prevent that by asking:

```
| pay portemonnaie amount == Nothing = Nothing
```

But apparently this is not possible. Does anybody have a more smarter way to build around this? Thank you

Comment: Use pattern matching, avoid partial functions.

Comment: also `map`, `fromMaybe` or `maybe` might be what you want here ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that that `Nothing` check comes *after* the call to `fromJust`. In your way of solving it, it should be this:

```
payment ::  [(Integer , Integer)] -> Integer ->  [(Integer , Integer)] -> Maybe  [(Integer , Integer)]
payment portemonnaie amount cashier | pay portemonnaie amount == Nothing = Nothing
                                    | content (fromJust (pay portemonnaie amount)) - amount == 0 = Just []
                                    | otherwise = payExact cashier (content (fromJust (pay portemonnaie amount)) - amount)
```

However, it could still be better. First off, since Haskell 2010 (or in Haskell 98 with the `PatternGuards` extension), it's easier to write this:

```
payment ::  [(Integer , Integer)] -> Integer ->  [(Integer , Integer)] -> Maybe  [(Integer , Integer)]
payment portemonnaie amount cashier | Nothing <- pay portemonnaie amount = Nothing
                                    | Just paid <- pay portemonnaie amount, content paid - amount == 0 = Just []
                                    | otherwise = payExact cashier (content paid - amount)
```

Furthermore, you could shorten some things by using a `where` clause:

```
payment ::  [(Integer , Integer)] -> Integer ->  [(Integer , Integer)] -> Maybe  [(Integer , Integer)]
payment portemonnaie amount cashier | Nothing <- mayHavePaid = Nothing
                                    | Just paid <- mayHavePaid, content paid - amount == 0 = Just []
                                    | otherwise = payExact cashier (content paid - amount)
  where
    mayHavePaid = pay portemonnaie amount
```

Comment: Thank you, that was very helpful. Yea I was just looking at the otherwise-guard and somehow oversaw, that the fromJust-call was also in the first guard. Also thank you for your further tips!

Answer (score 0):

Without any extensions it is still possible to write this quite readably (indeed, I would argue, more readably than the answer using pattern guards). First, notice that the one thing you do in all cases is `pay portemonnaie amount`, and that you must do different things depending on the result of that function: so, put it first, and pattern-match on it:

```
case pay portemonnaie amount of
  -- ...
```

The Nothing case is easy, so you can trivially add it in, and leave a blank for the Just:

```
case pay portemonnaie amount of
  Nothing -> Nothing
  (Just receipt) -> -- ...
```

Now, if there was a Just (which I'm calling receipt here, since I'm not sure what it is in your domain), then you always need to compute the leftover amount, so let's put that in a where clause:

```
case pay portemonnaie amount of
  Nothing -> Nothing
  (Just receipt) -> -- ...
    where outstanding = content receipt - amount
```

Now all that's left is to fill in the different guard clauses for the Just pattern, which is very easy now that the relevant values are already bound:

```
case pay portemonnaie amount of
  Nothing -> Nothing
  (Just receipt) | outstanding == 0 -> Just []
                 | otherwise -> payExact cashier outstanding
    where outstanding = content receipt - amount
```

And of course slot that expression back into the body of the actual function:

```
payment :: [(Integer, Integer)] -> Integer -> [(Integer, Integer)] -> Maybe [(Integer, Integer)]
payment portemonnaie amount cashier =
  case pay portemonnaie amount of
    Nothing -> Nothing
    (Just receipt) | outstanding == 0 -> Just []
                   | otherwise -> payExact cashier outstanding
      where outstanding = content receipt - amount
```